# How to upload an image with cordovaFileTransfer to my Spring service?

Tags: spring, ionic-framework, image-uploading

I am using ionic in my project and i need to take a picture with phone and upload picture to my server and save it.

I am using the next function to upload image but i think i am only sending the image path and not the image file

```
$scope.upload = function() {
    var options = {
        fileKey: "avatar",
        fileName: "image.png",
        chunkedMode: false,
        mimeType: "image/png"
    };
    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload("http://192.168.56.1:1337/file/upload", "/android_asset/www/img/ionic.png", options).then(function(result) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }, function (progress) {
        // constant progress updates
    });
}
```

I have String on my server. How i can receive the image file on my spring service???

Comment: this may be of some help for you, although it uses WCF Service and not Spring Service. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409547/wcf-service-phonegap-file-transfer-plugin-how-do-i-receive-image-with-parame

Comment: All my services are Rest services, soo i am looking for a solution in a rest service

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being too clear but the implementation in that post was also using Rest. What I was getting at is access the image from the HTTP Request object, that is what happens in the link I posted previously. I'm sure Spring will have a similar way of doing this?